# Flash Preloader with dynamic/random text from file

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I would like to have a preloader, which displays text from a text file in random order.
So let's say I have 15 lines of text in the file, and the preloader displays one randomly each 3 sec (till the App is loaded).

I only found a solutions where you always need to recompile the preloader when the text file changes...that's what I want to avoid.
Any ideas?

Thx,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

If your preloader is loading from an external textfile dynamically, I am not sure why you need to recompile the preloader. That's if the structure of your text file doesn't change.
I would put all display texts in an xml file and have the preloader load the xml file dynamically.